# Show that a matroid $M$ is connected iff, for every pair of distinct elements of $E(M),$ there is a hyperplane avoiding both.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-combinatorics, graphic-matroids

Here is the question I am thinking about:

Show that a matroid $M$ is connected iff, for every pair of distinct elements of $E(M),$ there is a hyperplane avoiding both.

It is in James Oxley book in chapter 4, section 1. Could anyone give me some hints to the idea of solving it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First recall that the complement of a hyperplane is a cocircuit, so this means that for every pair of elements, there exists a cocircuit that contains both. This implies that $M^*$ is connected, using Proposition 4.1.3 in Oxley. If you show that $M$ is connected iff $M^*$ is connected, you are done. To show the later, start with a pair of elements $\{a,b\}\subseteq C$ for a circuit $C$ and then $C\setminus \{a\}$ is independent, hence there is a basis $B$ such that $C\setminus \{a\}\subseteq B$, hence $B^* = X\setminus B$ contains $a$ but it doesn't contain $b$, so consider the fundamental circuit of $B^*$ w.r.t $b$, this will have $a$ and $b$ and so connectivity is transferred by duality.